# Feedback is needed: Describe the Galois group of the polynomial $x^5 -3 ∈ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)[x]$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

> Describe the Galois group of the polynomial $x^5 -3 ∈ \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)[x]$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, where $\zeta$ is a primitive fifth root of unity.

Here is what I attempted:

Since the splitting field of $x^5-3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt[5]{3})$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt[5]{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=20$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta):\mathbb{Q}]=4$ , 
it follows that $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt[5]{3}):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)]=5$.

And it is separable over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, so the galois group of $x^5-3$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ is isomorphic to a group of order $5$,

which has to be a cyclic group $C_5$.

I'd like to know whether there is a gap in the argument.

And any comment will be appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you also should note that the degree of $\zeta$ over the rationals is four.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thx :) I've edited it.

Comment: Perhaps add a little more justification to $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt[5]{3}):\mathbb{Q}]=20$.

Comment: Compared to the wording of the task your argument is quite indirect. Why not directly listing the automorphisms of the field extension?

Comment: @HagenKnaf I see. That's probably a better descrpition of the group. Thx.

Comment: I agree with @TokenToucan 's comment. Why is it so that $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt[5]{3}):\mathbb{Q}] = 20$? That is correct, but imo it is a gap in the argument.